# Multifeeds in simplepie, how to distinguish categories

Tags: php, simplepie

I have a multifeeds project created with Simplepie. It runs fine but now I want something that I can't achieve and haven't found any tutorial regarding how to get it.
My project consists on a news aggregator with various categories with arrays of links for each one.
I have setup two test pages to explain this better:
1st:http://goo.gl/0E3KQu
2nd:http://goo.gl/YO1mTv

**On the first example each category is separated and has a different border-bottom color (3 simplepie instances):**

```
<?php
require_once('../inc/autoloader.php');

$feednews= new SimplePie();
$feednews->set_feed_url(array('feed1',  'feed2','feed3',));
$feednews->init();
$feednews->handle_content_type();

$feedentertain= new SimplePie();
$feedentertain->set_feed_url(array('feed4','feed5','feed6',));
$feedentertain->init();
$feedentertain->handle_content_type();  

$feedtech= new SimplePie();
$feedtech->set_feed_url(array('feed7','feed8','feed9',));
$feedtech->init();
$feedtech->handle_content_type();
```

?>

```
<ul>    
News
<?php foreach ($feednews->get_items() as $item) : ?>
    <div>
    <span class="news">
    <span class="title"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></span> - 
    <span class="source"><?php $feednews = $item->get_feed(); echo $feednews->get_title(); ?></span>
    <span class="date"><?php echo $item->get_date("H:i a"); ?></span>
    </span>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>    
</ul> 

<ul>        
Entertainment
<?php foreach ($feedentertain->get_items() as $item) : ?>
    <div>
    <span class="entertain">
    <span class="title"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></span> - 
    <span class="source"><?php $feedentertain = $item->get_feed(); echo $feedentertain->get_title(); ?></span>
    <span class="date"><?php echo $item->get_date("H:i a"); ?></span>
    </span>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul> 

<ul>    
Tech
<?php foreach ($feedtech->get_items() as $item) : ?>
    <div>
    <span class="tech">
    <span class="title"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></span> - 
    <span class="source"><?php $feedtech = $item->get_feed(); echo  $feedtech->get_title(); ?></span>
    <span class="date"><?php echo $item->get_date("H:i a"); ?></span>
    </span>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

**On the second I followed a simplepie tutorial called how_to_group_multiple_posts_by_day (Merging Multiple Feeds), and they are all grouped (1 simplepie instance):**

```
<?php
require_once('../inc/autoloader.php');

$feed_genre['news'] = array('feed1','feed2','feed3',);  
$feed_genre['entertain'] = array('feed4','feed5','feed6',); 
$feed_genre['tech'] = array('feed7','feed8','feed9',);  

extract($feed_genre);
$feedall = new SimplePie();
$feedall->set_feed_url(array_merge((array)$news, (array)$entertain, (array)$tech));
$feedall->init();
$feedall->handle_content_type();    
?>
<?php
$stored_date = '';
$list_open = false;
foreach ($feedall->get_items() as $item):
{
$item_date = $item->get_date('F d'); ?>
<?php 
if ($stored_date != $item_date)
{
if ($list_open)
{
    echo '</span>' . "\r\n";
}
$stored_date = $item_date;
echo '<div class="">' . '<span class=""> ' . $stored_date . ' </div>' . "\r\n";
echo "\r\n";
$list_open = true;
}}
?>
<?php { ?>
<ul>
<div>
<span class="title"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink();     ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></span>
<span class="source"><?php $feedall = $item->get_feed(); echo $feedall->get_title();     ?></span>
<span class="date"><?php echo $item->get_date("g:i a"); ?></span>
</div>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What I want to do is:

Mix them all, grouped by day (as in the 2nd page).
Style each category color (as in the 1st page).

I hope I have explained myself clear, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, this is not clear enough to give an answer. If you are breaking them apart by category anyway, why mix them?

Comment: I broke them apart just to demonstrate a different style applied to each category, as I said my goal is to mix all categories in one list each with its own style.